# Memory compatibility?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm in the process of building a PC intended mostly for gaming and I've got a few questions. Currently, I only have the motherboard and CPU:

Motherboard: **GIGABYTE GA-Z68AP-D3**
CPU: **Intel Core i3-2120**

My main question is about memory compatibility. I have 4 **Hynix 2GB HMT125U7BFR8C-G7** with light-moderate use laying around and I'd love to save a few bucks if I can. I've read that this is server memory...

a) Will that be a problem for PC use?
b) Is it compatible with the motherboard?

I've emailed Hynix and checked Crucial to no avail. If incompatible, what memory would be a good fit given the components I have? The motherboard has 4 sockets and supports up to 32GB, but I don't know that I have the budget for that at the moment.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the memory is called server memory is because it is [ECC memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory), error correcting memory. This makes it much more expensive than normal memory, and thats why it is normaly not used in home computers. (normal computer operation can live with some errors now and then)

Other than that, it is DDR3 1066, the mainboard supports that type of memory. So, yes you can use it.

By the way, even if it should not work (dont see a reason why), memory prices are very low at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah memory _is_ dirt cheap right now, why couldn't I have had a nice video card laying around or something haha.